# query not selecting distinct

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
Test_ID   Question_ID    User_ID
---------------------------------
 15           1            1
 15           2            1 
 16           1            2
```

And I'm trying to go through the table and print out something like this for each user.

Test id: #
Number of questions: #

I'm using this which I can only get to print out the test id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Test_ID) AS Tcode, COUNT(Question_ID) AS Qcount,User_ID FROM user_answers WHERE User_ID = 1
```

Comment: Try `SELECT Testid, COUNT(Question_ID) AS Qcount, User_ID FROM user_answers WHERE User_ID = 1 group by Test_id`.

Comment: @chris85 That just prints the test ID number and nothing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group by` for aggregate function (and for this you don't need distinct)

```
SELECT Test_ID  AS Tcode, COUNT(*) AS Qcount, User_ID
  FROM user_answers
  WHERE User_ID = 1  group by Tcode, User_ID
```

Comment: It isnt working . I when i echo Tcode and Qcount , i just get the number 1

Comment: sorry it still isnt working . Its just prining out the test id number

Comment: I have tested in sql console the sql is right .. be sure you get the data from fetch (and eventually if id in not integer use User_ID = '1')

Comment: i too have it working in the console . Cant get it to work in php

Comment: Yes im connected and there are no errors. It just prints the test id

Comment: Just for test try var_dump($result) and give me a feedback

Comment: Nevermind , It works now , seems that one of my other functions was echoing when it wasnt supposed to